# XML code doesnt seem to work in JSP code on eclipse browser

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee

My problem is as I stated above. Couldn't find any solution worked for me nor the existing ones weren't specific enough to fit in my situation. Here's the detailed explanation:

I am using the Eclipse Indigo Java EE IDE on Windows 8 machine, trying to learn JSP and the web services environment by the tutorial "Up and Running with Java Applications" by Todd Perkins, using the built-in Tomcat v7 server in eclipse and mysql & apache from Xampp. I've taken the baby steps as instructed and saw it working in the built-in browser in eclipse. But when it comes to execute the following line

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

 <world>
<% 
Connection conn = null;
Statement stmt = null;
ResultSet result = null;

try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world","root","1234");
out.println("Connected to database.");

}catch(SQLException ex)
{
    out.println("Error connecting database");
}
%>
</world>
```

it just gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zr9wP.jpg) screen.

For clarification,

The xml tag **world** is the name of the database i'm using.
I omitted the heading directives from code.

Thank you all in advance for any suggestions. Any link to a similar problem that I overlooked is welcomed.

Comment: You forgot the most important part of the question: a clear description of the problem. What problem exactly do you have and what result exactly did you expect?

Comment: Sorry you're right. 
Expected output is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLraZ.jpg). Later on I hope to run [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vluOJ.jpg) snippet and to see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsKxd.jpg) result.The tag **tour** in the images is the database tutor used.

Comment: So it means it works as you expect in other browsers? Only Firefox is working differently?

Comment: No, I actually haven't run it in any other browser, just eclipse built-in browser. Expected result is from the tutor's screen in the video. I've seen some answers on the internet suggesting to update something related to the _Web Tool Plugins_. But i'm afraid that option belongs to some older version.

Comment: Then zack6849 is most probably right in his answer - displaying of XML depends on the browser.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek  wow it really was. I've just tested it on mozilla an t woks just as I expected. Don't know why I didn't tried that option before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like it'd doing **exactly** what you're telling it to do.

It's printing the xml tag, and then inside that tag, either an error message, or a successful message, in the same format you specified, what exactly are you expecting it to do?

If you're expecting the output that just has the word, maybe it'd be because your browser isn't displaying XML the same way as the instructors, could you post the entirety of your xml so we can see it?

Comment: Thank you. It was possibly something related with my eclipse browser. Switching to Firefox fixed the issue. I'll add the eclipse solution if I ever find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSP is working right. The output:

```
<world>Connected to database.<world>
```

... as seen in your browser is exactly what the JSP is producing. If it is seen differently in different browsers is probabily because you haven't specified an explicit content-type, and so, every browser applys its own defaults.

To avoid that, you'd better specify always a proper content-type. In your case:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/xml"%><?xml version="1.0"?>
<world>
    ...
</world>
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense. And must be the solution but I've tried and got the same output. Maybe there's a different way to achieve what you mean above or something is deeply messed up with my installation. Thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: Hm... Be sure no to be fooled by browser cache after you modify your JSP: Do a "refresh" from the browser (usually pressing F5), or better save your JSP with a new name.

Comment: Yes it fixed it. Actually I don't exactly know what I changed but I restarted the Tomcat server and do some "ctrl-x ctrl-v" ( as it's the magical way to make the nonsense errors go away in eclipse) and it showed the expected results nicely.